# Issues creating calendar on iphone (works only on simulator)

Tags: iphone, calendar, simulator

I have a code that creates a calendar programmatically, it is ok on the simulator but on the iphone it doesn't work. On my iphone, the calendar is linked with iCloud (maybe that's the reason).

every time I run the code I get the message that it was created and it's identifier:

```
[eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"created, saved, and commited my calendar with id %@", calendar.calendarIdentifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that... The problem was because iCloud, here is my solution:

```
     NSArray *allCalendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

         for (int i=0; i<allCalendars.count; i++) {
             EKCalendar *currentCalendar = [allCalendars objectAtIndex:i];


             if ([currentCalendar.title isEqualToString:@"tapCar"]) // YES
             {

                 calendarIdentifier = currentCalendar.calendarIdentifier;

                 calendarexiste=@"ok";
           }
         }

         if ([calendarexiste isEqualToString:@"ok"]) // YES
         {
             NSLog(@"there is a calendar");
              calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:calendarIdentifier];

         } else {

         NSLog(@"there is no calendar");
             // Create a new calendar of type Local... save and commit
             calendar  = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:eventStore];
             calendar.title = @"tapCar";

             UIColor *bluecolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(16/255.0) green:(161/255.0) blue:(233/255.0) alpha:1];

             [calendar setCGColor:bluecolor.CGColor];

             EKSource *theSource = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents].source;

             calendar.source=theSource;


             NSError *error = nil;
             [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];

             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"created, saved, and commited my calendar with id %@", calendar.calendarIdentifier);


             } else {
                 NSLog(@"an error occured when creating the calendar = %@", error.description);
                 error = nil;
             }

          }



         event.calendar=calendar;
```

But now I have the following error: Error getting shared calendar invitations for entity types 3 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"

Do someone knows why??